# Do vegetable seeds have a shelf life?

Tags: vegetables, seeds, germination

I bought vegetable seeds a few years back.  I tried planting them this year but am having mixed results (very few are sprouting).  Do seeds have a shelf life/expiration after which they will not germinate?  I am trying to figure out if the problem is with the seeds or something else.

Comment: Is this helpful to you? https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/24673/does-keeping-lettuce-seeds-in-an-open-package-affect-their-viability?rq=1.

Comment: That question is specific to lettuce but I am dealing with beets, carrots, etc. not germinating.  Looking for some practical experiences

Comment: I think the linked question is helpful as it discusses storage conditions with apply to basically all veggie seeds, not just lettuce.

Comment: Yes indeed they have a shelf life and the GOOD seed companies tell you what that length of time is; 1 year, 2 years, 5 years.  But remember that seed bank in Iceland?  Below freezing temps all year round...they have to continually replace seeds, depending on the seed.  I buy major seed every other year but never throw away any seed because if 8 out of 10 seeds germinate year 1 (85% is a good germination rate), the next year might be 6 or 7 if that seed had been kept cool and vacuum packed.  Depends on the type of seed, different plant's seed last differing years.

Comment: Where did you get your seed from, J.?  I get all mine these last few years from Territorial; non gmo, seed grown in my same state, and they put on their seed packets the length of time the seed will keep it's germination rate before it declines.  ie) Carrots Mignon F1; seed specs-Min. germ. standard:75%.  Usual seed life 3years.  Best directions and info I have found on any seed packet.  Cost was 3.85 for 1 gram. A little more expensive but to KNOW it is non gmo and a seed guarantee and to know it is not already 3 years old is worth the extra.

Comment: I bought mine from Costco.  All organic and non GMO verified.  It says packed for 2015 so not sure what that means. In any case, I seem to be getting zero germination rate so wondering if seeds expired all of a sudden.  I do store it indoors in the original package and conditions are cool (not in a refrigerator)

Comment: @JStorage " It says packed for 2015 so not sure what that means." It means the same as a "use by" date on food packaging - it was intended to be sown in 2015 (and therefore the seed was probably harvested in 2014). It's not too surprising the germination rate is lower in 2017. After a long storage time, it will also depends on how close to "perfect conditions" for germination you achieved in terms of temperature, moisture, soil pH and texture, planting depth, etc, etc. Fresh seed will tolerate more "abuse" than older seed.

Comment: @JStorage "All organic " - have you ever seen any "inorganic seed" for sale? That's just marketing BS - especially if the "organic" seed was packaged along with a random selection of "organic" bugs and viruses, rather than in a nice sterile environment!

Comment: @JStorage Ouch.  The words organic and natural have been completely ruined.  The fact your seed said 'non gmo' means you got some good seed.  That label does not have to be listed anymore so the companies that DO list non gmo have a bit more credibility.  They want knowledgeable clients.  If it was grown in 2014 makes total sense but you should still be getting some at least 50% germination.  I store all my seeds indoors, in the dark but not in the frig or freezer.  Not sure if I want to as yet. Keep the info about Territorial Seed from Oregon.  I've been very happy with their seed and plants.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, all seeds have an average "life span", but the length varies between species and is greatly influenced by storage conditions like temperature, humidity and light.

As a rule of thumb, dry, cool and dark, possibly in the original sealed package is the best way to store seeds.

The standard garden veggie seeds should typically<sup>1</sup> last at least two to three years under the aforementioned storage conditions. After that, you'll likely notice a drop in the germination rate, which you can counter by sowing a bit more generously (you can always thin the seedlings later). Consider a germination test for older seeds to get an idea of what you can expect from a particular batch

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course there is some variation. Unfortunately, I don't have a handy table or similar at hand. Check your seed packs for either a production date / year or some other date, e.g. a recommendation to use the seeds until a certain year. Some companies will give a "germination guarantee" until a certain date or similar.

Comment: Wish that was true for weed seeds 

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Stephie, but if you have old seeds, just try. Germination rate should still be above zero. I think 10 years is still significant, e.g. more than 1/3. Considering that often seed packs have too much seeds, it is still an option.

This year I put together a lot of seeds I had (few from '80, but most from 2000 to 2012). It was a real overseeding, in bad conditions (I didn't work too much the soil, because I didn't get much chances). Anyway I get a lot of seedlings from many different kinds.

From my experience (not so scientific): Cucurbitaceae (e.g. zucchini) and Apiaceae (carots) have good germination also after long time. Solanaceae (tomatoes) and Brassicaceae (radish, rucola) follow them.  I had more problem with beans: they dry quickly after few years of bad storage. I didn't have many seeds of Asteraceae (lactuces) and Amaranthaceae (Swiss chards), so I cannot really tell you about that.

Answer (score 4):

No, or may depend on the seed. When I had a vegetable garden, I had some seeds 15+ years old  . I didn't have a problem with sprouting. I did store them sealed in a refrigerator. At one time I thought 5 year old onion seed was bad, so to use it up I planted it very thick. That was a good weather year and it looked like I had a row grass in the garden. I may have a new data point; planted some 35 year old coral beans a couple days ago and they are  now swelling . I believe sprouting rates are 95 % moisture, temperature, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, light, heat and moisture degrade their viability/ability to germinate.

With the exception of bean and pea seeds (which form a hardened coating in response to cold), as soon as I'm done using them, I tape the envelope shut, then I put all my seeds that I want to try and reuse in a zip-closure plastic storage baggie (a thicker one, like "storage" or "freezer" variety, not the really thin "sandwich" ones), a pint or quart size is fine.  I add uncooked white rice (to absorb any excess moisture), squeeze out the extra air, seal it and store it in my basement fridge, in the crisper drawer, where it stays in cool dry darkness until the next planting session.

I have no problems with germination rates for at least two more years.  From Giaccomo's answer, looks like this can be pushed quite a bit further.  I generally never try to push it to a fourth.  This works great for peppers, tomatoes, cabbage family (inc. Brussels sprouts, broccoli, and cauliflower as well as cabbage), lettuce, squash/pumpkins..... you name it.